# How to rotate points from csv using orthographic projection d3

Tags: d3.js

I want to ask you for a help. I have copied this code (see: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5193723). I've changed the projection to orthographic and still loading points from csv file. Is it possible to rotate the globe also with points rotating? 
I have only found a possibility to rotate the globe but my points are not rotating. 
I would be gratefull for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be useful if you post the code when asking questions, this helps the community to better understand the question. In the example that you mention, the callback of the `zoom` event of the zoom behavior scales and translates the container group of the features. If you want to rotate the globe, you should change the rotation of the projection instead, and update the paths of the features.

I recently made [a gist](http://bl.ocks.org/pnavarrc/9730300) showing how to create a celestial sphere with the orthographic projection, and drawing the stars as small circles. In this gist, the drag behavior is used to rotate the globe.

```
// Rotate the sphere with drag behavior
var dragBehavior = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(Object)
    .on('drag', function(d) {
        projection.rotate([(d.x = d3.event.x) / 2, -(d.y = d3.event.y) / 2]);
        svg.selectAll('path').attr('d', function(u) {
            // The circles are not properly generated when the
            // projection has the clipAngle option set.
            return path(u) ? path(u) : 'M 10 10';
        });
    });
```

Note that there are better ways to rotate a sphere, for a better strategy, see [Jason Davis' article on rotating maps](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/). Regards,